# Ansible undefined facts about network interfaces

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm using docker ubuntu image and running ansible on it. "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_' + private_netif]['ipv4']['address'] }}"

script fails because ansible_eth0 is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Note that ansible will not gather facts about network interfaces when using docker image FROM ubuntu:18.04. It helps to install iproute2 package.

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y iproute2
```